# Postscript/note/additional info in a form

Tags: forms, symbols

In most ordinary forms, there is some addition information or notes that the form owner want to tell users. For example,

```
* Required
/ Staff only
```

I have seen different sets of symbol used in different forms, such as

```
* <some note>
**  <some note>
***  <some note>
```

Or

```
* <some note>
/ <some note>
# <some note>
```

Or

```
[1] <some note>
[2] <some note>
[3] <some note>
```

Any reasons make the note symbol different? Is there country-specific convention for this? What consideration should I make when I choose the symbol set?

Comment: I recognize that this was just an example, but unless you're closely mimicking a form that already exists on paper, you probably don't need to display "staff only" fields to the user in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Asteriks (*) are broadly used in form for specifying required fields, but that's the only thing that seems to be -more or less- a convention, there isn't any for notes in general.

Other notation like `*`,`**`,`***` and [1].[2],[3] are used frequently in "Terms and conditions" and in books respectively, so it's not the strange that they sometimes appeared in the web since there isn't a clear way to go.

An alternative approach that could be used at least in forms when there's enough space and the additional note is not too long is just to show it directly next to the input. When adding notes with references you give pretty bad user experience since the users has to deviate his view away from "the flow" of form completion. That also adds a lot of cognitive load without a sufficient reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most important issue is not the symbol set, but rather where you put the information corresponding to the symbols. Footnotes are user-unfriendly on paper and possibly even worse on the web. I'd recommend making the note information available when the user hovers / taps on the symbol.

If you do that, then I'd suggest using graphic symbols or emoji -- users are more used to being able to interact with graphical symbols to get additional information than they are with plain text symbols (there's the dashed underline convention for indicating that text has additional information, but I think that's excessively rare). Some options include ,, or ❓

If you want to go with standard characters, @rewobs is right that asterisks are commonly used to indicate required fields. Don't overload them with other meanings. I'd recommend going with the traditional sequence of symbols that come after *: which you could use: †, ‡, §, ‖, and ¶